# Which version of VB is used in SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services

Which version of Visual Basic does SSRS support?

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms156028.aspx) says that you write Visual Basic in the report code but doesn't say much about the version.

Comment: In my experience, the expression language used in SSRS feels more like VBA than VB.NET. In any case, since you can add a reference to any .NET assembly, I would guess the version depends on what version of SQL Server/Data Tools you're using. For example, with SQL Server 2014, I would guess the version is .NET 4.0 or maybe even 4.5. But why does it matter? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was curious about the version. Googled it. Found nothing. So I thought I should ask here on stackoverflow. Your comment answers the question. You can reply to the question. I will accept it as the right answer. P.S. I knew about adding assembly references to the report but I never thought about the version of the Data Tools. Interesting.

Comment: I'll leave my comment as a comment for now - perhaps someone more enlightened can shed additional light on the question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.  Microsoft are not very clear about this.  The RDL specification for SQL Server 2008 R2 states that expressions "are defined in a Visual Basic compatible syntax", but does not provide any other detail, except an obsolete link.  There is also no mention of custom code other than .NET references for precompiled dlls.

Code written in a report is stored as text within the RDL file after it is deployed, which means that it is either interpreted on the fly or JIT-compiled when it the report is run.  For this reason, if you have a large volume of, or intensive code, precompiling to a dll and referencing it in the report will offer better performance.

Comment: So your "answer" is "I don't know."?

Comment: My answer is that this is undefined